# Where are the immune people being kept safe?

Tags: the-maze-runner

I just finished the Maze Runner trilogy (the last book of the series which is The Death Cure) and I'm not really satisfied with the ending of the last book

At the end of the book all of the immunes ("munies") are to be put *somewhere* safe and the other people (outside) will be dead because of the Flare. But until that time, the immune ones must survive.

I really don't understand what kind of place could keep them safe. How can they provide food to avoid starvation, etc. Or is that place couldn't be a place that sick people can't get there. It can't be isolated outside of the world in the end. The place is still on Earth?

**Where were they being kept and why was it safe?**

Comment: Gladers were kept safe in the Glade (if they didn't had grievers to worry about). They had their own ecosystem and they pretty much managed it on their own.

Answer (score -1):

After Thomas escapes the vivisection, he rescues the immunes from the maze and takes them to the flat trans that Ava Paige has hidden in the maintenance room where Thomas and the gang used to hang out. They take it to Greenland, which is an isolated island that because of plate tectonics has shifted to become the perfect temperature.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! You've posted a lot of very brief, borderline-low-quality answers in a very short space of time. I think it would be better if you slowed down a bit and took more time to write your answers, including checking for spelling and grammar mistakes and sourcing quotes from the books to back up your assertions.